# Jquery loaded? Colorbox is available? Calling some js file via $.getScript are always downloading from the web server?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I am dynamically load js files with _tumIsler.js (_allStuff.js)

```
<script src="../js/_tumJsler.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It contains:

```
// url=> http:  +  //  + localhost:4399  + /yabant/
//       ----     ----   --------------    --------
//     protocol + "//" +     host        + '/virtualDirectory/'
var baseUrl = document.location.protocol + "//" + document.location.host + '/yabant/';

// If there is "~/" at the begining of url, replace it with baseUrl
function ResolveUrl(url) {
    if (url.indexOf("~/") == 0) {
        url = baseUrl + url.substring(2);
    }
    return url;
}

// Attaching scripts to any tag
function addJavascript(jsname, pos) {
    var th = document.getElementsByTagName(pos)[0];
    var s = document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    s.setAttribute('src', jsname);
    th.appendChild(s);
}

// I want to make sure jQuery is loaded?
addJavascript(ResolveUrl('~/js/1_jquery-1.4.2.min.js'), 'head');

var loaded = false; // assume it didn't first and if it is change it to true
function fControl() {
    // alert("JQUERY is loaded?");
    if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
        loaded = false;
        fTry2LoadJquery();
    } else {
        loaded = true;
        fGetOtherScripts();
    }
}

// Check is jQuery loaded 
fControl();

function fTry2LoadJquery() {
    // alert("JQUERY didn't load! Trying to reload...");
    if (loaded == false) {
        setTimeout("fControl()", 1000);
    } else {
        return;
    }
}

function getJavascript(jsname, pos) {
    // I want to retrieve every script one by one
    $.ajaxSetup({ async: false,

        beforeSend: function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                async: false,
                cache: true
            });
        },
        complete: function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                async: false,
                cache: true
            });
        },
        success: function() {
            //
        }
    });

    $.getScript(ResolveUrl(jsname), function() { /* ok! */ });
}

function fGetOtherScripts() {
    // alert("Other js files will be load in this function");

    getJavascript(ResolveUrl('~/js/5_json_parse.js'), 'head');
    getJavascript(ResolveUrl('~/js/3_jquery.colorbox-min.js'), 'head');
    getJavascript(ResolveUrl('~/js/4_AjaxErrorHandling.js'), 'head');
    getJavascript(ResolveUrl('~/js/6_jsSiniflar.js'), 'head');

    getJavascript(ResolveUrl('~/js/yabanYeni.js'), 'head');
    getJavascript(ResolveUrl('~/js/7_ResimBul.js'), 'head');
    getJavascript(ResolveUrl('~/js/8_HaberEkle.js'), 'head');
    getJavascript(ResolveUrl('~/js/9_etiketIslemleri.js'), 'head');
    getJavascript(ResolveUrl('~/js/bugun.js'), 'head');
    getJavascript(ResolveUrl('~/js/yaban.js'), 'head');
    getJavascript(ResolveUrl('~/embed/bitgravity/functions.js'), 'head');
}
```

After all these js files are loaded, this line is executing to show UploadFile page inside the page when clicked to the button which id is "btnResimYukle" .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (jQuery().colorbox) {
        alert("colorbox exists");
    } else {
        alert("colorbox doesn't exist");

        $.ajaxSetup({
            cache: true,
            async: false
        });

        $.getScript(ResolveUrl('~/js/3_jquery.colorbox-min.js'), function() {
            alert("Loaded ! ");

            $('#btnResimYukle').live('click', function() {
                $.fn.colorbox({ iframe: true, width: 700, height: 600, href: ResolveUrl('~/Yonetim/DosyaYukle.aspx') });
                return false;
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

First i want to ask you very good people, i am always calling js files with $.getScript function. Are they always downloading in every $.getScript requests? And if the answer "yes", how can i prevent that? Does this work:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true,
    async: false
});
```

[image: Js files coming from cache]

Second, i am always getting this error when i press F5 or Ctrl+F5 :
[image]

[image]

But when i press enter key on url, there is no error :s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your load script is appending the scripts to the head element, where they will be later handled in DOM order. This means that they are loaded after the inline script in your head element so, of course, you get and object expected error: jQuery has yet to be defined.  A better approach is to load only the absolutely necessary scripts in the header -- those required for your inline scripts to run -- and move the rest of the scripts, including your inline scripts, to the end of the body section of the document.  This way all of the document elements can still load in parallel, speeding up your page load.

If you do this, I would recommend not loading the scripts asynchronously.  If you load them synchronously, you'll find that you can move more of them to the end of the document.  Combine the scripts as much as you can to reduce load time even further.

Comment: First, I want to thank you because of you answered my question :) I was telling my friends about your cv. Second, i am requesting synchronously with "$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true, async: false });" line. Third, yes you are right, my code was working when i put inline scripts to the end of the page. When i moved them to the head, they didn't work. If i am mistaken please correct me, every js file requests in the head tag, are caching and next request, they are calling in the cache of browser!

Comment: The way you have it set up they scripts should use the cache -- your ajaxSetup is overkill, btw -- it should be enough just to set `async: false, cache: true` and skip the before/complete handlers.  It won't help you though because the script isn't going to be parsed until after the inline script the way you have it set up even if it comes from the cache.  Personally, I don't see any advantage to using getScript in this instance.  Just add a script element and let the browser handle the caching and load sequence.

Comment: I wanted to use only 1 js file that includes every js files.So, i wouldn't need to add script tag to every page's header. I read in some where if $.ajaxSetup({async:false }) is only work for one ajax call, next call will be sync. Thats why i used before, complete handlers. If i only write attach scripts to head tag with javascript, will it work? I tried but i saw, some inline scripts didn't work. Do you think its about first inline scripts work then scripts are attaching to the head? (THANK YOU SO MUCH Your advices)

Comment: If your inline script is dependent on an external script, that external script **must** be completely loaded before the inline script.  You might want to try using a master/child page set up with a content place holder at the bottom of the body element for scripts).  In you master page (just before the content place holder), include all of your common scripts using normal script includes, then any common inline scripts.  In each child page, in the script content block, first include the external scripts for that page, then any inline scripts for that page.  Combine as many externals as you can